# php warning illegal string offset 'order'

Tags: php

I'm receiving this waring on every page of my website, the error message is as below:
[image]

the code that the waring is refering to is like below:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Order the array by a key
 * 
 * @param array $a The array to sort
 * @param string $subkey The key used for the sorting
 * @return array Array sorted
 * 
 * @since 1.0                
 */   
function yiw_subval_sort( $a, $subkey ) {
 if( is_array( $a ) AND ! empty( $a ) ) {
  foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
   $b[$k] = strtolower( $v[$subkey] );
  }
  
  asort( $b );
  
  foreach( $b as $key => $val ) {
   $c[] = $a[$key];
  }
  
  return $c;
 }
 
 return $a;
}   
?>
```

line 19 is this line:

$b[$k] = strtolower( $v[$subkey] );

I do see there's couple of questions on stack overflow point to such problem but I've tried everything, nothing works, please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the $subkey element exists, like so:

```
if (isset($v[$subkey])) {
    $b[$k] = strtolower( $v[$subkey] );
} else {
    $b[$k] = '';
}
```

This should also resolve the header warning by preventing the error text.

Comment: Thank you so much! fixed it!